# Euler characteristic of Cauchy surface in Lorentz manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, general-relativity, special-relativity

Are there any known topological restrictions on what kinds of manifolds can form the Cauchy hypersurface of a Lorentzian manifold? I'm particularly interested about restrictions on Euler characteristics.

If the above question is too general, I am specifically interested in the two subcases:

1. What if we require the Cauchy hypersurface to be compact?
2. And/or what if we require the ambient manifold to be flat?

#### Motivation

(Copied from comments below)

I'm trying to find a certain kind of tiling system of Minkowski space, where there are finitely many polyhedral tile shapes (up to Poincare equivalence). There are local rules for assembling them into a Cauchy surface, and rules for evolving the surface. In 3d (2 space and 1 time) I haven't found an interesting example and am wondering if there is something I should know about Euler characteristic that would restrict my search.

I think in general with tiles and local rules for assembling them you can get arbitrary flat Lorentz manifolds including ones with compact Cauchy hypersurfaces (definitely seems true in 2d) so I'm looking for any results, compact or not, that might suggest something about my situation. I have a feeling that the finiteness of the tiling system might make compact results relevant, but who knows.

Comment: Without the restriction of (local) flatness, you could take any compact Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and consider $S^1\times M$ with the Lorentzian metric $-\mathrm{d}\theta^2 + g$.

Comment: @WillieWong:  Strictly speaking, you are right, but then a 'compact $n$-dimensional Lorentzian manifold' (as the OP originally specified) would never have any true Cauchy surfaces, so the OP's question (which, as it turns out, was not correctly formulated to reflect his intent) would not make any sense.  Thus, I chose to interpret 'Cauchy surface' in this case as 'local Cauchy surface', i.e., a space-like slice that meets all of the time-like geodesics (i.e., light rays).

Comment: @Robert, I rewrote the question based on OP's comments to Misha's answer. I hope I didn't miss anything in the copying!

Comment: @David: can you specify whether the dimension you mentioned are the space-time dimension or the spatial dimension? Your last comment on Misha's answer seems to suggest that when you wrote 3d you are talking about 2 spatial and 1 temporal directions, but I am not 100% sure I understood you right.

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks for improving my question! Yes, when I said 3d I meant 2 spatial, 1 temporal.

Comment: @RobertBryant: what is a "true Cauchy surface"? I guess I've been thinking of "local Cauchy surface." For instance if one identifies the points {x,t}<-->{x,t+1} and {x,t}<-->{x+1,t} in 2d Minkowski space (I'm sure there's a better way to say this), you get a compact Lorentz manifold, no? in which case I'm thinking of the points {x,0} as forming a compact Cauchy surface.

Comment: @David: a Cauchy surface requires that "inextensible time-like curves intersect the surface _exactly_ once". I objected (briefly) to Robert Bryant's comment because most inextensible time-like curves in his example intersects the surface infinitely often.

Comment: @WillieWong:  Well, I think you have to be careful about what you mean by 'intersect':  For example, if you take the Lorentzian metric $dx\circ dy$ on the (compact) torus $\mathbb{R}^2/\mathbb{Z}^2$, then the space-like curve $x=y$ intersects each null curve exactly once in the set-theoretic sense, but, apparently, you don't want that to be a Cauchy surface since that would violate the `theorem' you quoted in your (now deleted) comment.

Comment: @Robert: time-like is not the same as null. The reason why I (and most sources) state relative to the (open) "time-like" condition rather than the (closed) "null" condition is precisely that the given a closed time-like curve that intersects the surface once, you can always perturb it slightly to make it intersect (in the set-theoretic sense) the surface twice, giving a curve that demonstrably violates the "Cauchy" condition.

Comment: @WillieWong:  Oh, you are right; I read 'time-like' and thought 'null'.  (I do know the difference, of course; I just had an 'input error'.)

Comment: @RobertBryant: no problem! I expected as such. I expanded a little bit on my response mostly for the benefit of lookers-on.

Answer (score 4):

I read your question as the one about compact Cauchy surfaces in locally flat space times. Then the answer is negative: Take quotient of upper hyperboloid $H$ in $R^{2,1}$ (i.e. the hyperbolic plane) by a torsion free discrete cocompact subgroup $\Gamma$ in $SO(2,1)$. The Euler characteristic will be negative. Now, take the future light cone $C$ in $R^{2,1}$ and take the quotient $C/\Gamma$. This is your locally flat space-time, containing $H/\Gamma$ as a Cauchy hypersurface. This manifold is, of course, incomplete, but, if I remember correctly, Geoff Mess proved that you cannot have a compact Cauchy hypersurface in a complete locally flat Lorentzian manifold.

Edit: On the other hand, there are topological obstructions for existence of locally flat Lorenztian metrics. For instance, suppose that $M$ is a compact n-dimensional simply-connected manifold which does not immerse in $R^{n+1}$. For instance, $CP^2$ is an example of such manifold. Then $M\times R$ does not admit a locally flat Lorentzian metric, even incomplete one. (This follows because the developing map to $R^{n,1}$ of such a structure would yield an immersion to $R^{n,1}$.

Talking about tiles: My guess is that you are actually trying to construct complete locally flat Lorentzian metrics. It is known (proved by Geoff Mess) that such metrics do not exist on manifolds of the form $M\times R$, where $M$ is **compact** and hyperbolic. I will check, by now there is probably a reasonably good description of $M$'s for which such metric exists. On the other hand, if you take $M$ which is a noncompact surface, then such a metric does exist; these are so called *Margulis space-times*. One even has some nice description of their fundamental domains (tiles) due to Todd Drumm.  The trick is that the tiles are not convex. 
(Google "crooked planes" to learn more about them.) I am not sure if $M$ will be a Cauchy hypersurface in this case, I would have to check.

See e.g. [here](http://www.umpa.ens-lyon.fr/~barbot/ARTICLES/Cargese.Barbot.Zeghib.pdf) for a somewhat dated survey.

Comment: However, your locally flat ambient Lorentzian manifold $C/\Gamma$ is not compact, which the OP wanted (though, of course, such an example would not be of physical interest).

Comment: @RobertBryant: Maybe I misinterpreted the question, but my understanding of Cauchy hypersurfaces is that physicists want to have a manifold of the form $M\times R$, foliated by Cauchy hypersurfaces $M\times t$ ("time machines" are not allowed). Hopefully, OP will clarify if he wanted a compact space-time of a compact Cauchy hypersurface, that was unclear from the question.

Comment: I think your understanding of what physicists would want (and what is physically permissible) is correct, but the OP wrote 'compact $n$-dimensional Lorentzian spacetime', implying that the spacetime itself is to be compact.  As you say, perhaps the OP did not intend this and will so inform us.

Comment: Thanks for your replies...my DG is not up to speed so it will take me some time to digest. Here is where the question came from. I'm trying to find a certain kind of tiling system of Minkowski space, where there are finitely many polyhedral tile shapes (up to Poincare equivalence). There are local rules for assembling them into a Cauchy surface, and rules for evolving the surface. In 3d I haven't found an interesting example and am wondering if there is something I should know about Euler characteristic that would restrict my search. (to be continued...)

Comment: I think in general with tiles and local rules for assembling them you can get arbitrary flat Lorentz manifolds including compact ones (definitely seems true in 2d) so I'm looking for any results, compact or not, that might suggest something about my situation. I have a feeling that the finiteness of the tiling system might make compact results relevant, but who knows.

Comment: @DavidHillman: Before we get into your new questions (I have something to say about them but will do it later), you should clarify the question which you asked in the post. Namely, What is supposed to be compact: Cauchy hypersurface or the entire space-time? I hope, you understand the difference.

Comment: Yes, of course, sorry, brain failure. Compact spacetimes: not interesting to me. (And that result about Euler characteristic of compact spacetimes is probably irrelevant.) I was thinking about compact Cauchy surfaces, closed surfaces that you make from finitely many tiles (in my tiling example), the classic case being in 2d where your surfaces are circles and spacetime is a cylinder. And also interested in the case where the surfaces aren't compact, such as Minkowski space. And, compact or no, the flat case is of particular interest.

Comment: @Misha: you're right, these locally flat Lorentz manifolds produced by tilings would be complete.

Comment: @Misha: on the topic of completeness: the reason I say the manifolds would be geodesically complete is that the rules for assembling polyhedra are such that each point has a compact neighborhood that looks like Minkowski space. I previously discussed the setup a bit in <http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153970/> and learned that I was working with $(G,X)$ structures. But I guess now that the word compact above makes them more restrictive. Is completeness the main extra property that arises?

Comment: @DavidHillman: This condition is insufficient for completeness. Look at the example I gave. If flat Lorentzian manifold is also compact then it is complete ( this is not obvious).

Comment: David: You have to be careful with completeness in Lorentzian setting. The right definition is that all geodesics extend indefinitely (more formally, the exponential map is defined on the entire tangent bundle). The Cauchy criterion, in contrast, is no longer useful since you do not have a metric space, so thinking in terms of R-balls is not a good idea.

Comment: @Misha: Okay, more brain failure; ignore what I said about compact neighborhoods. The key in my situation is that there exists a number r>0 such that for every point there is an open ball centered at that point of radius r that looks like Minkowski space. Now we get completeness, right? (I will look at your example, but it will take some time; have to understand things like torsion free discrete cocompact subgroup of SO(2,1).)

Comment: Do you really want to use r-balls with respect to the Lorentzian metric? Maybe in presence of a compact Cauchy hypersurface this is a good concept, I am not sure.  With this assumption, I do not have any examples apart from the Minkowski space-time itself.

Comment: Oops: Misha's reply to my comment about open balls showed up for some reason after I was re-editing it, so things are out of order. Okay, right, no metric balls. Silly me. So I'll try saying it this way. Each polyhedron looks like a polyhedron in Minkowski space. If you take any point on the boundary of a polyhedron and consider all the polyhedrons hitting that point, the complex of these polyhedra looks like it's in Minkowski space. So geodesics extend, because they extend in Minkowski space. (By "looks like it's in Minkowski space" I mean there is the appropriate isometry.)

Comment: @DavidHillman: I see what you mean. It depends on your notion of polyhedron. Do you mean an intersection of closed half-spaces in $R^{2,1}$?  Then, if I remember correctly, there are no interesting examples (meaning, examples whose fundamental group contains a free subgroup). Here I am assuming, in addition, that you have completeness since it is unclear to me why completeness follows from existence of such tiles (in a similar setting of tiling of hyperbolic plane, there are examples of incomplete metrics which admit such tiling). But if you allow nonconvex tiles, still closed as subsets...

Comment: of $R^{2,1}$, then interesting examples abound (Margulis space-times). On the other hand, I am sure that in this setting existence of tiles does not imply completeness. You really have to do some reading, say, read the survey that I linked.

Comment: @Misha: yes, my polyhedra are intersections of closed half-spaces (the sides are on null hyperplanes). Convex. Thanks for all your help; you've given me some things to investigate.